# Shunting Yard Algorithm with unnecessary parentheses

Tags: javascript, algorithm, shunting-yard

Input (in javascript) is "3-2+(8-3)"

I want to translate this expression to Reverse Polish Notation. 
However, according to the algorithm, I can get "3 2 8 3 - + -", which doesn't evaluate to the result 12..... Any work around method for this? I know the parentheses are unnecessary here, but, oh well...I have my function below:

```
function ShuntingYard(str){
    str=str.replace(/\)\(/g, ")*(");
    var arr=str.split("");
    var sYqueue=[];
    var sYstack=[];   
    while (arr.length>0){
        var token=arr.shift();
        if (/\d+/.test(token)){
            // if it's a number, push to the queue
            sYqueue.push(token);
        } // end if
        else if (/[+]|[-]|[*]|[\/]/.test(token)){
            // if it's an operator
            if (sYstack.length==0){
                // if an empty operator stack
                sYstack.push(token);

            }
            else{
                while ((/[*]|[\/]/.test(sYstack[sYstack.length-1])) &&
                    (/[+]|[-]/.test(token))){
                        // if the TOS has operator with higher precedence
                        // then need to pop off the stack
                        // and add to queue
                        console.log(sYstack);
                        sYqueue.push(sYstack.pop());
                    }
                    sYstack.push(token);

            }
        } 
        else if (/[(]/.test(token)){
            // if it's left parenthesis
            sYstack.push(token);
        }

        else if (/[)]/.test(token)){
            // if it's right parenthesis
            while (!(/[(]/.test(sYstack[sYstack.length-1]))){
                // while there's no left parenthesis on top of the stack
                // then need to pop the operators onto the queue
                sYqueue.push(sYstack.pop());
            } // end while
            if (sYstack.length==0)
            { // unbalanced parenthesis!!
                console.log("error, unbalanced parenthesis");
            }
            else
            {
                sYstack.pop(); // pop off the left parenthesis
            }

        }
        else{
            // other cases
        }

    } // end while


    // now while the stack is not empty, pop every operators to queue
    while (sYstack.length>0){
        sYqueue.push(sYstack.pop());
    }
    return sYqueue;

} // end function ShuntingYard
```

Comment: why the result should be 12 instead of 6.

Comment: Your reg exps could be a lot simpler [abc] means any one of a, b or c. If you have just a single item in the brackets [a] then you can replace it with a single character. You can also use them instead of | for alternatives so a|b can be written as [ab]. In particular /[+]|[-]|[*]|[\/]/ can be replace with /[+=*\/]/ and /[(]/ replace with simply /(/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long time ago in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/aaditmshah/6683499) far far away I wrote an implementation of Dijkstra's shunting yard algorithm in JavaScript:

```
function Parser(table) {
    this.table = table;
}

Parser.prototype.parse = function (input) {
    var length = input.length,
        table = this.table,
        output = [],
        stack = [],
        index = 0;

    while (index < length) {
        var token = input[index++];

        switch (token) {
        case "(":
        stack.unshift(token);
            break;
        case ")":
            while (stack.length) {
                var token = stack.shift();
                if (token === "(") break;
                else output.push(token);
            }

            if (token !== "(")
                throw new Error("Mismatched parentheses.");
            break;
        default:
            if (table.hasOwnProperty(token)) {
                while (stack.length) {
                    var punctuator = stack[0];

                    if (punctuator === "(") break;

                    var operator = table[token],
                        precedence = operator.precedence,
                        antecedence = table[punctuator].precedence;

                    if (precedence > antecedence ||
                        precedence === antecedence &&
                        operator.associativity === "right") break;
                    else output.push(stack.shift());
                }

                stack.unshift(token);
            } else output.push(token);
        }
    }

    while (stack.length) {
        var token = stack.shift();
        if (token !== "(") output.push(token);
        else throw new Error("Mismatched parentheses.");
    }

    return output;
};
```

Here is how you would use it:

```js
var parser = new Parser({
    "*": { precedence: 2, associativity: "left" },
    "/": { precedence: 2, associativity: "left" },
    "+": { precedence: 1, associativity: "left" },
    "-": { precedence: 1, associativity: "left" }
});

var output = parser.parse("3 - 2 + ( 8 - 3 )".split(" ")).join(" ");

alert(JSON.stringify(output)); // "3 2 - 8 3 - +"
```

```html
<script>function Parser(a){this.table=a}Parser.prototype.parse=function(a){var b=a.length,table=this.table,output=[],stack=[],index=0;while(index<b){var c=a[index++];switch(c){case"(":stack.unshift(c);break;case")":while(stack.length){var c=stack.shift();if(c==="(")break;else output.push(c)}if(c!=="(")throw new Error("Mismatched parentheses.");break;default:if(table.hasOwnProperty(c)){while(stack.length){var d=stack[0];if(d==="(")break;var e=table[c],precedence=e.precedence,antecedence=table[d].precedence;if(precedence>antecedence||precedence===antecedence&&e.associativity==="right")break;else output.push(stack.shift())}stack.unshift(c)}else output.push(c)}}while(stack.length){var c=stack.shift();if(c!=="(")output.push(c);else throw new Error("Mismatched parentheses.");}return output};</script>
```

This, incidentally does not (and never will) evaluate to `12`, but this does:

```js
var parser = new Parser({
    "*": { precedence: 2, associativity: "left" },
    "/": { precedence: 2, associativity: "left" },
    "+": { precedence: 1, associativity: "left" },
    "-": { precedence: 1, associativity: "left" }
});

var output = parser.parse("3 * 3 - 2 + 8 - 3".split(" ")).join(" ");

alert(JSON.stringify(output)); // "3 3 * 2 - 8 + 3 -"
```

```html
<script>function Parser(a){this.table=a}Parser.prototype.parse=function(a){var b=a.length,table=this.table,output=[],stack=[],index=0;while(index<b){var c=a[index++];switch(c){case"(":stack.unshift(c);break;case")":while(stack.length){var c=stack.shift();if(c==="(")break;else output.push(c)}if(c!=="(")throw new Error("Mismatched parentheses.");break;default:if(table.hasOwnProperty(c)){while(stack.length){var d=stack[0];if(d==="(")break;var e=table[c],precedence=e.precedence,antecedence=table[d].precedence;if(precedence>antecedence||precedence===antecedence&&e.associativity==="right")break;else output.push(stack.shift())}stack.unshift(c)}else output.push(c)}}while(stack.length){var c=stack.shift();if(c!=="(")output.push(c);else throw new Error("Mismatched parentheses.");}return output};</script>
```

There you have it: a generalized implementation of Dijkstra's shunting yard algorithm in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your function logic: the previous operator must be popped from the stack to the output queue in 2 cases:
1. It's precedence is higher(your code handles this case).
2. It has the same precedence and a new operator is left-associative(which is the case for plus and minus).
The second case is not covered in your code, so it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is an expression parser engine (implementations for JavaScript/PHP/Python and ActionScript), on [github Xpresion](https://github.com/foo123/Xpresion) (ps. i'm the author)

The engine is quite flexible and configurable, one can create parsers that parse any expression which also includes polymorphic operators and general n-ary operators (eg. **ternary if-then-else**)

The algorithm is quite general (one could say, a generalised variation of [Shunting Yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm))