# Split string in javascript into an array

Tags: javascript, eval

I am using the eval() function to create an calculator, and as you know eval returns a string (I am referring to [this tutorial](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/javascript-css3-calculator)), for example `20+30`. What I want now is to split this string so I will have an array of data like `[20,30,50]` where the `20` and `30` are the operands and `50` is the result in this case.

What I did so far is:

```
var input = document.getElementById('screen');
var result= '20+30'; // as an example
var firstOperand = result.split('+', 1); //this is taking the first operand
```

What I really want is as I mentioned to turn my input value that is string `"20+30"` to an array: `myArr = [20,30,50]`.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the power of maps and reduce!

```
result = '1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9';
a = result.split('+').map(function(x){ return parseInt(x) });
b = a;
b.push(a.reduce(function(p, c) { return p+c; }));
// b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 45]
```

Btw you shouldn't use eval(), look into the [Shunting-yard algorithm instead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). Code examples for the algorithm can be found here at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222141/shunting-yard-algorithm-with-unnecessary-parentheses) and at [Rosettacode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/Shunting-yard_algorithm#JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

you can create the array passing to the split function only the separator.

```
var myArr = result.split('+');
```

now you need to add the result:

```
myArr.push("50");
```